# jQuery get ids of siblings

Tags: jquery, selector, siblings

I'm trying to get ids of siblings.

```
<ul>
    <li id="a1">a1</li>
    <li id="a2">a2</li>
    <li id="a3">a3</li>
    <li id="a4">a4</li>
</ul>
```

When I click on one of the li's, I want to select all sibling ids separated by comma.
Ex. I click on #a2 and get #a1, #a3, #a4. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `.siblings`

```
$('li').click(function () {
   var selEl = [];
   $(this).siblings().each(function (idx, el) {
       selEl.push('#' + el.id);
   });

    //.join would return you comma separated but 
    //if you want a space after comma then you need to pass .join(', ')
    console.log(selEl.join(', ')); //click on #a2 and get #a1, #a3, #a4
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lpw4u/1/

Comment: I was playing around with siblings().attr('id')... so yeah, this works. I modified '#' + el.id. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through siblings and store ids in an array.

```
$("ul li").click(function(){
    var s = $(this).siblings();
    var ids= [];
    s.each(function(){
       ids.push(this.id);
    });
});
 var commaSparatedIds = ids.join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
    var ids = [];
    var self = this;
    $(this).siblings().each(function(){
        if(self != this)
            ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    alert(ids.join(','));
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li[id^=a]').on('click', function() {
    alert($.makeArray(
      $(this).siblings()
         .map( function() {
           return $(this).attr('id'); 
         })
       ).join(', '));
});
```